# How to compare two CRM solutions and find the difference?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

What is the best way to compare two `CRM (2011)` Solutions and find the differences?. We have two solutions one is `QA-Solution` other is `Production-Solution`, I want to find out the differences between them. Actually i need to apply all the changes on `Production-Solution` and then we will deploy that solution somewhere else by using `CRM's Solution Import Export` functionality.

Comment: Are you just looking for data model changes or form changes of ribbon changes or everything?

Comment: Everything, any type of modifications.

Comment: If you're only concerned about applying all the changes, and not what the changes were, it may make more sense to merge the solutions within CRM 2011.  Are this solutions managed or unmanaged?  Are they created by the same publisher?

Answer (score 3):

The solution file contains the web resources, and an XML file that defines the solution.  You should be able to unzip the two solution files, and use a file diff utility to compare the two folder structures.  The results aren't going to be very pretty, but it shouldn't be too difficult to at least identify what web resources have changed, and what entities have been updated.

### Edit

Be aware that any data changes (ie, creating new Contacts) you've made will not be found in the solution export.  This also includes some other things like Duplication Rules, if you've made any....

Answer (score 1):

[Customization Comparer](http://crmcustomcompare.codeplex.com/) is a Code Plex tool for comparing the customization XML that you may find helpful.  For other files, Daryl's answer is a good option.

Comment: +1 for the moment. @pedro Azevedo: let me check it and if i found it helpfull i will accept it. thanks

Comment: This tool needs a lot of improvement!